# Tmux Macro/Function

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I'm trying to make a function in tmux so that when desired, I can bring up the command prompt (Ctrl-B, :) and type this in and have tmux spawn a new window in my existing session with a number of panes running a few specific commands.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like this:

Create a file called `~/foo.conf`

```
neww -n foo
send-keys -t foo cd ~/ C-m
send-keys -t foo vim C-m
split-window -t foo
```

We'll use `neww` to create the new window, then we'll issue commands to that new window. 
Using `C-m` sends the Enter key so the command executes. You could 
also pass the command to `neww` directly.

Then in your `~/.tmux.conf`, bind it to a key

```
bind z source-file ~/foo.conf
```

This is just one way to pull this off. This particular scenario names the window, but with a little ingenuity, I'm sure you can come up with a workaround for that.
Every tmux command can be issued from the .conf files, and can also be issued by passing it to `tmux` itself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to use a bash script in place of the conf and have it spit out the .conf settings?  I want to setup some simple server monitoring groups, and be able to pass a hostname through to this, otherwise I'll have a LOT of binds.

Comment: Yes, just use a bash script and preface each command with tmux. Programs like tmuxinator do pretty much that.